# как сравнить значения json dart/flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Суть кода заключается в том что, пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль,
Нажимает кнопку –активирует метод alertLogin
Это все улетает на сервер , в случае если нет логина или нет совпадений с паролем. То возвращает “nonLogin” . все работает.
Только мне хотелось бы, чтобы значек alert и кнопка  выполняли разные команды, в случает успеха или не удачи.
Я не могу сообразить что нужно сравнивать. Чтобы менять значения
К примеру:
Идеально было-бы если алерт вставить в эту строку, но так не получается.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data!.login);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
```

И метод  я не могу сравнивать

```
setLogin(String login, String password)
```

вот весь код

'''

class LoginController {

```
Future<Client> getClient(String login, String password) async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    'https://hamlacaapp.000webhostapp.com/json/auth.php?login=$login&password=$password'));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return Client.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}
```

}

```
 Future<void> alertLogin(BuildContext context, String login, String password) {
return CoolAlert.show(
  context: context,
  type: CoolAlertType.success,
  widget: setLogin(login, password),
);
```

}

```
setLogin(String login, String password) => FutureBuilder<Client>(
    future: getClient(login, password),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data!.login);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Я скину пример, как это делаю я. Не самый лучший, но должен помочь

```
bool _isError = false;
List<Client>? friends;

Future<void> _fetchFriends() async {
    friends = await FriendService.getUserFriends();
    if (friends != null) {
      setState(() {
        _isError = false;
      });
      showTopSnackBar(
        context, 
        CustomSnackBar.success(message: 'Все загрузилось!')
      );
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _isError = true;
      });
      showTopSnackBar(
        context, 
        CustomSnackBar.error(message: 'Какая-то ошибка')
      );
    }
  }
```

FriendService - это класс, где я как и ты пишу запрос к серверу просто и все (http.get). showTopSnackBar - это из пакета [top_snackbar_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/top_snackbar_flutter)

Дальше в методе build можно так

```
_isError == true ? Text('Там какая-то ошибка') : Text('Все загрузилось')
```